# Do nested commutators show up when commuting more than two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

If I want to commute two matrices $A$ and $B$, I obtain their commutator as an error term:
$$AB = BA + [A,B].$$
I would think that, to generalize this to $n$ matrices, I would obtain nested commutators in the error term, but I cannot seem to work this out (if it is indeed true). For example, for $3$ matrices:
$$ABC = BCA + [A, BC],$$
which was obtained by commuting $A$ with $BC$. Alternatively:
$$ABC = (BA + [A,B])C = BAC + [A,B]C = B(CA + [A, C]) + [A,B]C = BCA + B[A,C] + [A,B]C,$$
which was obtained by commuting $A$ with $B$ and then $A$ with $C$. Clearly the two end results above are equal. However, after trying to do some algebra, I cannot seem to write this as a nested commutator.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to write
  $$A X_1 X_2 \cdots X_{n-1} = X_1 X_2 \cdots X_{n-1} A + E,$$
  where $E$ contains a term with $n-1$ nested commutators containing all of the matrices $A$, $X_i$?
- If the above is not possible, is it possible when all the $X_i$ commute?

Comment: $ABC=BAC+[A,B]C=BCA+[B,C]A+C[A,B]+[[A,B],C]$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't clear what you are asking for. When $n=3$, if you mean to write $ABC-BCA$ as a sum of some members among $[A,[B,C]],
[B,[C,A]]$ and $[C,[A,B]]$, it's an impossible task. Let
\begin{aligned}
a&=ABC,\\
b&=ACB,\\
c&=BAC,\\
d&=BCA,\\
e&=CAB,\\
f&=CBA.
\end{aligned}
Then
\begin{aligned}
\left[A,[B,C]\right]&=A(BC-CB)-(BC-CB)A=a-b-d+f,\\
[B,[C,A]]&=B(CA-AC)-(CA-AC)B=d-c-e+b,\\
[C,[A,B]]&=C(AB-BA)-(AB-BA)C=e-f-a+c.
\end{aligned}
Clearly, $ABC-BCA=a-d$ is not a linear combination of $[A,[B,C]],
[B,[C,A]]$ and $[C,[A,B]]$. This is true even if $B$ and $C$ commute (so that $a=b$ and $d=f$). We do have
$$
ABC-BCA=ABC-BAC+BAC-BCA=[A,B]C+B[A,C],
$$
but the RHS involves multiplications of matrices with commutators.